# slurm is ignoring the --distribution=cyclic flag in my sbatch file and using the 'block' distribution method instead

Tags: slurm

I would like to distribute my job evenly across multiple nodes and have specified the --distribution=cyclic in my sbatch file, but slurm ignores that and uses the block distribution instead.

Before, the tasks were distributing evenly across the nodes.  From reading the docs, this is what I expect the default behavior to be, unless otherwise specified in slurm.conf.

Starting today, the tasks are clustering on the first node with only one task on each of the other nodes.  I've obviously changed something in the config, but can't figure out where to fix it.  I did make a change to the image for the compute nodes and rebooted them today.

When I try to stop the slurmctld on the head node, it is restarted immediately by my Bright Cluster Manager monitor.  Not sure if this is preventing configuration updates or not.

I've investigated the slurm.conf file but it looks OK.  I've tried both SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core and CR_CPU but get the same result.

To try and work around this I added the --distribution=cyclic to my sbatch file, but slurm is still allocation using the 'block' method.  But adding this to the sbatch should not be necessary, at leas according to my understanding of the docs.

Here are the relevant lines from slurm.conf and my sbatch script:

```
# RESOURCES
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
# Node Description
NodeName=DEFAULT Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=20 ThreadsPerCore=1
# Scheduler
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
```

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=12
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --distribution=cyclic:cyclic
```

I would expect the tasks to be distributed evenly between the nodes, with 4 tasks on each of the 3 nodes.

Here is how the tasks are actually getting distributed:

```
   NODELIST       STATE  CPUS(A/I/O/T)  MEMORY TMP_DISK REASON
 compute001       mixed     10/30/0/40  192006     2038 none
 compute002       mixed      1/39/0/40  192006     2038 none
 compute003       mixed      1/39/0/40  192006     2038 none
 compute004        idle      0/40/0/40  192006     2038 none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html, the distribution flag is only useful for srun:

> Specify alternate distribution methods for remote processes. In sbatch, this only sets environment variables that will be used by subsequent srun requests.

(As to *why* it's like this… I have no idea.  But it does appear it's by design.)

Depending on your configuration, you may be able to approximate what you want by setting SelectType=cons_res or cons_tres and SelectTypeParameters=CR_LLN.  If either of these parameters changed recently, that might be the reason the behavior changed, as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I totally missed the part where it only sets environment variables.  That explains a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to manually distribute my processes across the nodes by modifying the sbatch file to limit the number of tasks assigned to each node:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=12
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=4
```

This results in the expected distribution of the tasks across the nodes:

```
   NODELIST       STATE  CPUS(A/I/O/T)  MEMORY TMP_DISK REASON
 compute001       mixed      4/36/0/40  192027     2038 none
 compute002       mixed      4/36/0/40  192027     2038 none
 compute003       mixed      4/36/0/40  192027     2038 none
 compute004        idle      0/40/0/40  192027     2038 none
```